# findViewById must be void but can't make it void

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use findViewById in my code, but it must be void, what is wrong? I don't want to have the Method clickbutton but if I take it out, it says it must be void. Is there any way I can do this without changing everything in my code?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class LoginWorker extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    Button login;
    EditText user, pass;
    ToggleButton repass;
    TextView invail;

    private boolean savelogin = false;

public void clickbutton() {


        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bloginf);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernametf);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordtf);
        invail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invalidinfo);
        repass = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.rememberlogintb);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(user.getText().equals("parents")){
                    if(pass.getText().equals("!saints")){
                        if(repass.isChecked()){
                            savelogin = true;
                            setContentView(R.layout.announcements);
                        }
                    }else if(!repass.isChecked()){
            savelogin = false;
            setContentView(R.layout.announcements);
        }
    }if(!user.getText().equals("pie")){
        invail.setText("Invalid Username and / or Password!");
    }if(!pass.getText().equals("!pie")){
        invail.setText("Invalid Username and / or Password!");
    }
}
}); 
}
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I suggest you follow a beginner's tutorial on Android: [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102065/Android-A-beginner-s-guide).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `onCreate` function it seems. `onCreate` is Called when the activity is starting. This is where most initialization should go. Have all the above code you have inside this [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) function. Before going further you should study the activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).  i.e what happens when an activity is created and in which order the functions are called. This will tell you how to implement what you want. Also as @vikram suggested a tutorial would help you to start.

Comment: When I do this I have to change all of my variables to final and it still says it need to implement unimplemented methods.

Comment: Unimplemented method would be `onClick(View)`. This is because `LoginWorker` implements `View.OnClickListener` imterface. Implementing an interface requires your class to implement methods defined in the interface. I suggest you follow a tutorial on Java before following a beginner's tutorial on Android. Also, if your variables are defined as global, the `final` keyword will not be required.

Answer (score 1):

where is your `onCreate` ,you must call it and `setContentView(R.layout.***);`

Answer (score 0):

You need this code. Try watching some YouTube videos to help with the process of understanding what all this does.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   //All of your apps code goes here.  
}
```